# MYSQL Dumps entire database and ignores QUERY

Tags: php, mysql

iI'm using this PHP code to dump a column from a MYSQL table into a text file, but it ends up either dumping no data or the entire database as opposed to acknowledging the SQL statement and only dumping the data from that column itself. What am i doing wrong?

```
$file = 'file.txt';
if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file);      
$sql = 'SELECT column FROM table';
```

I tried to different command lines,
The line below:
`$cmd = 'mysqldump  --user=xxx --host=localhost --password=xxx mydatabase \''.$sql.'\' > '.$file;`

Dumps a group of text such as,

```
    -- Server version   5.0.95-community   
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

and this line, dumps the whole database to the file:

```
$cmd = 'mysqldump --user=xxx --password=xxx --host=localhost mydatabase > file.txt';
exec($cmd);
```

I know in the line above i'm not actually querying the database, but that's the part i need probably need assistance with.

Comment: the mysql command can take a query as an argument but not mysqldump. Why aren't you just using the mysql functionality of PHP?

Comment: That is what i was using previously but it takes an enormous amount of time to perform on a repetitive scale.

Comment: perhaps the better question would be how do i optermise XXX, being the original (proper) way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, a custom command line a [user built for a similar issue](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?599062-Using-quot-mysqldump-quot-to-export-individual-fields...&s=2b3f13d066d8a2ca9a37a71efa17cc7b&p=4144788&viewfull=1#post4144788).

So now i have:

```
$cmd = "mysql --user=xxx --password=xxx --host=localhost --database=xxx --execute='SELECT `column` FROM Table LIMIT 0, 10000 '> file.txt";
exec($cmd);
```

That does exactly what i need. The only problem is that it doesn't work from XAMPP, only on my web server. Maybe some light needs to be shed on that. Thanks to those who provided their code as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) ever taking a query as an option.

Perhaps just.. run the query?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a connection, running the query, `fopen('file.txt', 'w')`, then loop through the query results and `fwrite` to file.

Maybe something like this... of course your connect string will be different. I didn't test it so I would double check everything before making it live.

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


$file = 'file.txt'; 

$sql = 'SELECT column FROM table'; 

$results = mysql_query($sql , $conn);

$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
foreach($results as $line){
    fwrite($fh, $line);
}

fclose($fh);
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: I responded to a similar comment above as well, i used this process and it takes an enormous amount of time to do repetitively

Comment: Yeah, maybe... I guess it depends on how many results are returned.

Comment: the column has email addresses in them, up to 1500 email addresses at estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql client with custom query instead of mysqldump:

```
$cmd = 'mysql --user=xxx --password=xxx --host=localhost --skip-column-names mydatabase -e \"SELECT column FROM table\" > file.txt';
exec($cmd);
```

Comment: I tested this and it dumps a list of mysql functions as opposed to a queried database.

Comment: The main idea is to run "mysql --user=xxx --password=xxx --host=localhost --skip-column-names mydatabase -e "SELECT column FROM table" > file.txt" command . Please make sure that check user, password, host and query parameters are valid.

Comment: I doubled checked all of my login credentials, and it still outputs the same result.

Comment: There must be a problem with the command-line flags then. Check them.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there add the -w option then conditions from the where clause of your select eg:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p  dbname tablename -w "id > 100 and income > 2000;" > output.txt
```

Comment: For example like this?<br /> `$cmd = 'mysqldump -w --user=tower --password=brinard --host=localhost tower_pschamber -e \"SELECT Email FROM Profiles WHERE ID > 1\" > file.txt';`
<br />
I tried your method and it produced the results, and i have no `WHERE` conditions in my `SELECT` statement, only `SELECT email from Profiles`